# Confusion Matrix for ten classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, confusion-matrix, transfer-learning

My goal is to compute a confusion matrix from a huge dataset with 10 classes, so far I got the following code and results:

**Note:** As far as I know is doing the correct predictions over all the classes, I computed the loss in a pre-training phase, and the accuracy during this Transfer classification phase and they behave as expected, my problem comes in the obtention of the predicted labels from the outputs.

```
train_dataset = Subset(eurosat_dataset, train_indices, train_transforms)
val_dataset = Subset(eurosat_dataset, val_indices, val_transforms)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batchsize, shuffle=False, num_workers=2, pin_memory=False,
                          drop_last=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batchsize, shuffle=False, num_workers=2, pin_memory=False,
                        drop_last=True)

print('train_len: %d val_len: %d' % (len(train_dataset), len(val_dataset)))

 #for i, data in enumerate(val_loader):   # inputs = data[0], labels = data[1]
#    inputs, labels = data               # inputs [1,13,224,224], labels[0-9] --> classes
#    if i > 10:
#        break
#    print(inputs.shape, labels, inputs[0].max())

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
#inputs = inputs.to(device)

# Get the model, definition of the model to be loaded
import models.models_mae_mod as models_mae_mod
from models.util.pos_embed import interpolate_pos_embed  # import pos_embed.py ----> Run OK


def prepare_model(chkpt_dir, arch='mae_vit_small_patch16'):
    # build model
    model = getattr(models_mae_mod, arch)(in_chans=13)
    # load model
    checkpoint = torch.load(chkpt_dir, map_location='cpu')
    state_dict = model.state_dict()
    for k in ['head.weight', 'head.bias']:
        if k in checkpoint and checkpoint[k].shape != state_dict[k].shape:
            print(f"Removing key {k} from pretrained checkpoint")
            del checkpoint[k]

    # interpolate position embedding
    interpolate_pos_embed(model, checkpoint)
    msg = model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'], strict=False)
    print(msg)
    return model


# loading the model
chkpt_dir = 'C:/Users/hugo_/PycharmProjects/transfermodel_Eurosat/datasets/B_raw_norm.pth'
model_mae = prepare_model(chkpt_dir, 'mae_vit_small_patch16')
model_mae = model_mae.to(device)
model_mae.eval()

print('Model loaded.')

with torch.no_grad():
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(val_loader):
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        outputs = model_mae(inputs)  # 0 is LOSS, 1 is [1, 196, 3328] is PRED, 2 is [1, 196] is MASK,
                                     # 3 is [1, 13, 224, 224] is TARGET
        #_, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        #outputs = outputs[-1:]
print("set")
```

I'm not computing the confusion matrix this time since the Outputs format is not the correct to get it.

```
nb_classes = 10

confusion_matrix = torch.zeros(nb_classes, nb_classes)
with torch.no_grad():
    for i, (inputs, classes) in enumerate(val_loader):
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        classes = classes.to(device)
        outputs = model_mae(inputs)
        outputs = outputs[3]
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        for t, p in zip(classes.view(-1), preds.view(-1)):
            confusion_matrix[t.long(), p.long()] += 1

print(confusion_matrix)
```

I identified my problem as the way I'm getting the Outputs, which is the correct one but not enough to get the information I want, **how to get those predicted labels and use them for the calculation of the Confusion Matrix?**

I attach an image of my debugging process for a better understanding:
[image: Outputs]

Comment: Are you sure _"there are no wrong predictions"_? The confusion matrices I usually see have the correct predictions on the diagonal.  Maybe the model is only predicting one class?

Comment: As far as I know is doing the correct predictions over all the classes, I computed the loss in a pre-training phase, and the accuracy during this Transfer classification phase and they behave as expected, **my problem comes in the obtention of the predicted labels from the outputs**, I will edit the question and let visualize where I think my problem is, which seems more like the understanding on how to get that information more than the correctness of the model/dataset.

Comment: @rickhg12hs You were right in some sense, after discussing the model I was taking the wrong one, the outputs were just part of the pre-training stage not the transfer learning one, thus how will I get any predicted labels or even any classification task if I'm not performing transfer learning? That's why the results had non-sense regarding the prediction of the classes, therefore, wasn't even predicted something but the reconstruction of an image. My fault was misunderstanding of the concepts.